# Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type

Tags: sqlite, python-3.4, openpyxl

I am creating an SQL db and trying to iterate over an excel file and put all the data in to the SQL table as follows but I keep getting an annoying error. I have looked at the data types and still can't get my head around it please let me know if anyone spots what the problem is my code is:

```
import sqlite3
from openpyxl import load_workbook

#wb = load_workbook(r"LeaguePlayers.xlsx")

#read workbook to get data
wb = load_workbook(filename = r"LeaguePlayers.xlsx", use_iterators = True)
ws = wb.get_sheet_by_name(name = 'Sheet1')
#ws = wb.worksheets



conn = sqlite3.connect("players.db") # or use :memory: to put it in RAM

cursor = conn.cursor()

# create a table
cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE players
              (player TEXT,
               team TEXT,
               points INTEGER, 
               cost REAL,
               position TEXT) 
           """)


#Iterate through worksheet and print cell contents
for row in ws.iter_rows():
    for cell in row:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO players VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", row)

    conn.commit()

#----------------------------------------
# display SQL data
#----------------------------------------
c.execute('SELECT * FROM players')
for row in c:
    print (row)
```

The error i get says:

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO players VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)", row)
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.

Answer (score 1):

I really think you need to do some kind of introduction to Python.

You are making two elementary mistakes: looping of the **cells** in a row but passing the **row** to the query; passing a complex object as opposed to a native Python type such as an integer or string.

Something like the following is what you want:

```
player = [cell.value for cell in row]
cursor.execute(query, player)
```

Note, that execute takes a sequence (tuple or list) as the second argument.

Comment: yes i'm a novice. but i'm trying very hard to get up to speed with sqlite and how to get data from excel in to a table. I have spent a couple of days messing with sqlite and openpyxl so i'm not an expert by any stretch of the imagination. Thanks for your response but i'm having trouble understanding what 'query' does when I have nothing in my program referencing ;'query'. I apologise in advance if i offend you with my noob mistakes.

Comment: sorry my mistake you mean by query my insert query.

Comment: `query` is the SQL statement you want to run. I only wrote pseudo-code for you to use as a guide. It's fairly common practice to define the query before you execute it.

There are lots of good Python tutorials around. You should invest some time in them or pick up a copy of the Python Cookbook. It will save you a lot of time and frustration.

Comment: No error snow but cannot select any data from the SQL database. I dont think it is inputting the data in to the database. Thanks I'll pick up the python cook book. Is the python cook book compatible for python 3.4?

Comment: You may need to commit the changes to the database. If you write to a file you can look at the database with a command line tool or even the raw file. Should be able to recognise stuff. Good luck.